# Win ctrl+alt+delete equivalent in Elementary?

Tags: system

I know that in Elementary **ctrl+alt+del** means *Log Out*.

What I am looking for is an equivalent to windows **ctrl+alt+del** which activates *Task Manager*, so that I can close/shut down frozen task?

I know that one can use **ctrl+alt+F1** to get to *console* (**ctrl+alt+F7** to get back to *GUI*) but that doesn't help me much... ?

Sometimes **ctrl+F4** seem to kill some active windows? but it doesn't work when things freeze...?

So what's the best way of handling things like this in Elementary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Windows just maps that shortcut onto activating its task manager by default. You could replicate it by installing a system monitor (like [gnome system monitor](https://apps.gnome.org/app/gnome-system-monitor/) or [Monitor](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.stsdc.monitor/) for elementary os) and bind a shortcut to it if you don't want to do that stuff via terminal.

You can install Monitor via PPA instead of flatpak by following these quick instructions here: https://github.com/stsdc/monitor

```
sudo apt install -y software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stsdc/monitor
sudo apt install com.github.stsdc.monitor
```

I would check out https://askubuntu.com/a/95202/672975 as it might answer your question.

Comment: thank you! I am not bothered by what actual combination of keyboard keys is used as a shortcut (I know I can customise it). What I really wanted was a way of turning "Task Manager" (or it's Linux equivalent) when things get frozen... I will try your recommendations and report back (I can't find Monitor in AppCenter... not updated for EOS 6)

Comment: Ahh, yes it is, actually, you just have to install via ppa instead of flatpak by following these quick instructions here: https://github.com/stsdc/monitor

Comment: Thanks for that! it is very confusing, because on elementary Monitor webpage (https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.stsdc.monitor/) it clearly states that "...This app is only available for elementary OS 5.1 Hera..." Installing (with instructions from github now)

Comment: Yes, that message refers to being able to install the app from the AppStore GUI only. Elementary OS is  undergoing a transitioning in packaging of software from .deb to flatpak for its apps, and many app developers are playing catch up to repackage their apps and test for new bugs or different behavior due to sandboxing, etc.